# Put layout above another one centered

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have one `Layout`centered in my `ScrollView`and I want to put an `ImageView`just above that `Layout`without moving its position.

How can I achieve that??

Here is my **code**:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    // LinearLayout with elements centered in ScrollView    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        ...Elements inside layout...

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

//ImageView I want to put just above LinearLayout without moving its position:
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageViewLogoFactor_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_factorenergia" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout like this:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLogoFactor_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutMain2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            />        
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yes, perfect! I tried with RelativeLayout but I forgot `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`